# Approximate P(number of accidents < 10)

Tags: probability, probability-theory

> The number of accidents in a given city are $0, 1, 2, \text{or} 3$, with probabilities $0.94, 0.03, 0.02, 0.01$ respectively. Approximate the probability that, during $100$ days, the number of accidents are less than $10$.

**Thoughts:**

Let $X_t, t = 1, 2, ..., 100$ be a collection of random variables where $X_t$ indicates the number of accidents on day $t$. Suppose $X_t$ are pair-wise independent for all $t$. Then I could calculate the mean and variance of $X_t$ and proceed with a normal-distribution approximation by means of the Central Limit Theorem.

This was my first idea on how to approximate this probability. I'm looking for some alternatives though, as I would have to suppose $X_t$ are pair-wise independent in my approach. Alternatives involving Chebychev's and Markov's inequalities are particularly welcome (though I don't see how they would fit in here at first glance).